# ActiveMQ Artemis max-redelivery-delay and deadletterqueue

Tags: activemq-artemis, messagebroker, dead-letter

We are using the broker ActiveMQ Artemis 2.26.0, and I'm trying to set up a redelivery mechanism on a queue.

I would like for some messages to be retried for 72h maximum with progressive back-off. After 72h the message should be sent to a DLQ.

[The doc](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/undelivered-messages.html) states that both mechanisms of message redelivery and dead-letter queue can be combined, so I tried the following, using the examples provided with ActiveMQ Artemis:

`broker.xml`:

```xml
      <address-settings>
         <!--override the redelivery-delay  for the example queue-->
         <address-setting match="exampleQueue">
            <redelivery-delay>30000</redelivery-delay>
            <redelivery-delay-multiplier>2.5</redelivery-delay-multiplier>
            <dead-letter-address>deadLetterQueue</dead-letter-address>
            <max-redelivery-delay>259200000</max-redelivery-delay>
         </address-setting>
      </address-settings>

      <addresses>
         <address name="deadLetterQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="deadLetterQueue"/>
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="exampleQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="exampleQueue"/>
            </anycast>
         </address>
      </addresses>
```

It seems that with this configuration the message are sent to `deadLetterQueue` after 10 redeliveries (default value of `max-delivery-attempts`).

How do I combine these values to fit my scenario?

Comment: The number of retries isn't configured based on the total time you want to take. It's configured by each individual retry. You just need to a little math to calculate how many retries at which multiplier with what delay will execute for 72 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL; DR; you need to set a `max-delivery-attempts` value greater then 10

The total delivery delay is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) so it is `<redelivery-delay>*(1-<redelivery-delay-multiplier>^<max-delivery-attempts>)/(1-<redelivery-delay-multiplier>)`

In your case the total delivery delay is `30000*(1-2.5^10)/(1-2.5)=190714863` that is less then 72h (259200000) so to fit your scenario you need to set a `max-delivery-attempts` value greater then 10, i.e. with `max-delivery-attempts` = 11 the total delivery delay is 476817158 (132h) that is greater than 72h.